# doFilter is calling too many times

Tags: struts, servlet-filters

This is my filter mapping in web.xml :-

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
    <filter-class>
        org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
       <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
    <dispatcher>FORWARD</dispatcher>
</filter-mapping>
<filter>
    <filter-name>LoginFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>login.LoginFilter</filter-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>test-param</param-name>
        <param-value>This parameter is for testing.</param-value>
    </init-param>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>LoginFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
    <dispatcher>FORWARD</dispatcher>
    <dispatcher>INCLUDE</dispatcher>
</filter-mapping>
```

my URL is like
     "localhost:9966/RemindMe/"

When i paste this Url in browser doFilter method is calling many times.

This is my doFilter method :-

```
  public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res,
        FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
    try {
         HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) res;
            response.sendRedirect("./login.jsp");
            return;
    } catch (Exception e) {
         System.out.println("Exception is " + e);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

By "too many times" to you mean "infinite"?

Your filter redirects (the browser makes another request), which means your filter is hit, which means the browser makes another request, which means...

Comment: no its not calling infinite times, may be 20 to 30 times.

Comment: @BipinBangwal And then...? The only reason it would stop is that the container or the browser realizes it's in an infinite redirect loop.